# I am trying to return the item num, item size, item colour and a count of how many items of a given colour and size there are

Tags: oracle

Here is the table -

```
create table inventoryItem (
       itemNum    varchar(10) not null
              references itemType(itemNum) on delete cascade,
       code   varchar(20) not null,
       qtyInstock float       not null,
       itemColor  varchar(15),
       itemSize   float,
       primary key (itemNum, code)
```

This is the values -

```
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('B1', 'hbk', 50, 'white', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'hbk', 25, 'green', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C2', 'hbk', 20, 'black', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C1', 'ebk', 70, 'black', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A3', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 2.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A2', 'pbk', 50, 'green', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'ebk', 15, 'green', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C2', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 3.0);
```

Further explanation - I want to create a view showing the `itemNum` `itemSize` `itemColor` and a count of how much `qtyInstock` there is for each instance of a color and size. For example - how much stock is there for a black shirt in size 3 or a white shirt in size 2. I've been lost for hours and have no idea how to go about this. Please help! Thank you to anyone who comments :)

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to search for `SQL COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I tried to but I couldn't find any examples that were similar to my issue that I could understand

Comment: Every example of a SELECT that uses COUNT and GROUP BY is similar enough, as the basics are all you need. I'd suggest you try harder - it will help you learn better.

Comment: The very first example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) shows you the basics and the syntax for using COUNT and GROUP BY together. You can list the columns you want in any order. Every column that is in the SELECT that is not aggregated has to be in the GROUP BY clause. That should give you enough to at least make an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I kind of underdstand GROUP BY. This was my attempt at it but it is not the answer I am looking for. ```select itemSize, itemColor, qtyInstock as stock_combination
from inventoryItem
group by itemSize, itemColor, qtyInstock;```

Comment: I know this is probably very easy for you but I don't see why this query isn't leading to what I want.

Comment: Actually, you don't want COUNT(), you want SUM(). Add one more column to your SELECT that is SUM(TheColumn), where `TheColumn` is the column that you want to total. (I just re-read your original question.) `SUM` is another aggregate function, and works like doing a `SUM` in Excel or summing a column of numbers on a sheet of paper. `COUNT()` would give you the number of rows, not the sum of values, but would be added the same way. Just remember that when using an aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG), all columns that are in the SELECT that are not aggregated must be in the GROUP BY.

Comment: I see, I have changed it to SUM now but it shows multiple instances of black with size 3. There are 3 instances of this with a total stock of 80 however, the query returns with 3 instances of black in size 3. One with 20 and two with 30.

Comment: Then you didn't use SUM correctly, or you've got something wrong in your GROUP BY. Take a look at what you've written carefully, and you can probably figure out what you missed.

Comment: As an aside, in oracle you should be using VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your current query:

```
SQL> select itemnum, itemsize, itemcolor, sum(qtyinstock) qty
  2  from inventoryitem
  3  group by itemnum, itemsize, itemcolor;

ITEMNUM      ITEMSIZE ITEMCOLOR              QTY
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
A0                  4 green                   40
A0                  3 black                   30  --> 3 black
C1                  4 black                   70
C2                  3 black                   50  --> 3 black
A2                  3 green                   50
B1                  4 white                   50
A3                  2 black                   30

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you said, there are just too many rows for size: 3 / color: black. That's because of `itemnum`, so - one option is to remove it from query:

```
SQL> select itemsize, itemcolor, sum(qtyinstock) qty
  2  from inventoryitem
  3  group by itemsize, itemcolor;

  ITEMSIZE ITEMCOLOR              QTY
---------- --------------- ----------
         4 white                   50
         4 green                   40
         3 green                   50
         4 black                   70
         2 black                   30
         3 black                   80  --> 3 black

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now there's only one row, but - obviously, you don't have `itemnum`s any more. If you do need that information, one option is to *aggregate* them:

```
SQL> select listagg(itemnum, ', ') within group (order by itemnum) items,
  2         itemsize,
  3         itemcolor,
  4         sum(qtyinstock) qty
  5  from inventoryitem
  6  group by itemsize, itemcolor;

ITEMS                  ITEMSIZE ITEMCOLOR              QTY
-------------------- ---------- --------------- ----------
A3                            2 black                   30
A0, C2, C2                    3 black                   80  --> 3 black
A2                            3 green                   50
C1                            4 black                   70
A0, A0                        4 green                   40
B1                            4 white                   50

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I guess that this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: This actually perfect, thank you very much. I’m fairly new to SQL so I haven’t gone into depth about aggregation but I will definitely learn it now. Thanks!